# LINQ: Convert Dictionary<int, Object> to List<List<string>>

Tags: c#, linq

Class definitions:

```
public class Site
{
        public Site(){}
        public string SiteId{get;set;}
        public int Value{get;set;}
}

public class HubObject
{
        public HubObject(){}
        public Site Hub{get;set;}
        public List<Site> Sites{get;set;}
}
```

My `Dictionary<int, HubObject> result` contains..

```
Key               Value
0                 {Hub={"Hub0", 600}, Sites={{"Chicago", 100}, {"Minneapolis", 200}, {"Newyork", 300}}}
1                 {Hub={"Hub1", 300}, Sites={{"Portland", 100}, {"Santaclara", 200}}}
```

want to convert it to `List<List<string>>` in below format.

```
"SiteId",   "Value"
"Hub0", 600
"Chicago", 100
"Minneapolis", 200
"Newyork", 300
"Hub1", 300
"Portland", 100
"Santaclara", 200
```

This is what I have achieved so far

```
var sitesList = result.SelectMany(r => r.Value.Sites.Select(x => new
                {
                    x.SiteId,
                    x.Value
                })).ToList();
```

This gives me...

```
"SiteId",   "Value"
"Chicago", 100
"Minneapolis", 200
"Newyork", 300
"Portland", 100
"Santaclara", 200
```

How do I add "Hub" rows to this? Like, first `Hub0` parent followed by all sites that it belongs to it and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can do like this:

```
var sitesList=result.SelectMany(r => 
    {
        return r.Value.Sites
           .Concat(new List<Site>{r.Value.Hub})
           .Select (s =>new{s.SiteId,s.Value});
    });
```

You can even do this as well:

```
var sitesList=result.SelectMany(r => 
            new List<Site>{r.Value.Hub}.Concat(r.Value.Sites)
               .Select (s =>new{s.SiteId,s.Value}));
```